# How do I pair the elements in the first list with all the elements in a second list in SML?

Tags: list, functional-programming, sml, smlnj

The Problem Statement: Write a function pair that takes two lists of integers and generates a list of pairs, where each pair is a combination of each element from each list.

For example, `pair ([1,2], [3,4,5])` should return

```
[(1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5)].
```

My work so far:

```
-fun pair(a:int list, b:int list) = if null a then nil else if null b then nil else (hd a, hd b)::pair(a, tl b)@pair(tl a, b);

val pair = fn : int list * int list -> (int * int) list

-pair([1,2],[3,4,5]);

val it = [(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,5),(2,4),(2,5),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5)]
```

I've tried to trace the function to find out why the `(2,5)`, `(2,4)`, `(2,5)` are showing up but I'm not seeing it clearly still.

It seems straightforward enough but I can't seem to get the last bits ironed out. Some assistance pinpointing why those elements are being added in the middle would be of help.

Thanks.
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're recursing over both lists.

If you look at your example,

```
pair ([1,2], [3,4,5]) -> [(1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5)]
```

you will see that it has two sublists,

```
[(1,3), (1,4), (1,5)]
[(2,3), (2,4), (2,5)]
```

where the first consists of pairs formed from the first element of `[1,2]` and every element of `[3,4,5]`, and the second is the second element of `[1,2]` also paired with every element of `[3,4,5]`.
Note that each sublist contains all of `[3,4,5]` but only one element of `[1,2]` - the first is the same as `pair ([1], [3,4,5])` and the second is `pair ([2], [3,4,5])` - so you should only need to recurse over the first list.

You can create such a list like this:

- If any input list is empty, the result is empty.
- Otherwise:

  1. Take the first element of `a` and pair it with every element of `b` in a list (hint: think about `map`.)
  2. Recursively make pairs from the tail of `a` and all of `b`.
  3. Combine the results of 1 and 2.

With pattern matching:

```
fun pair ([], _) = []
  | pair (_, []) = []
  | pair (x::xs, ys) = <something involving x and ys, suitably combined with 'pairs (xs, ys)'>
```

It might help if you write step 1 as a separate function.

Comment: I did in fact write the first step as a separate function for another problem in the problem set. I overlooked the fact that I could use my "append" function (concatenating one int to all elements in an int list) to implement pair. We were not to use pattern matching in this example, but the general flow is shown here in your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an exercise, I'm not going to show you the answer to the problem statement.

What you're trying to generate is called the cartesian product of the two lists.

Your current approach (formatted a bit nicer),

```
fun pair (a, b) =
  if null a then nil else
  if null b then nil else
  (hd a, hd b) :: pair (a, tl b) @ pair (tl a, b);
```

produces duplicate results down the line because you leave out `hd b` in `pair (a, tl b)` and you leave out `hd a` in `pair (b, tl a)`, but on the second iteration of e.g. `pair (a, tl b)`, the first element of `a` is processed once again for each remaining element of `tl b`.

You can avoid this duplication of work by addressing each element *once*. I would recommend that you look at the functions `map` and `concat`. The general approach is this: For every element `x` of `a`, generate `(x,y)` for every element `y` of `b`. "For every element" is `map`. And

```
map (fn x => ...something with (x,y)...) a
```

produces a *list* of results, just like you want. But if you repeat the same approach of `map (fn y => ...) b` as the `...something with (x,y)...` part, you'll run into an inconvenient surprise that `concat` can help you with.

You can solve this exercise without using `map` and `concat` and instead using manual recursion, but you might have to split the work into two functions, since you'll want one function that folds over the `x` of `a` and, for each `x`, fold once over `b`. The function `map` takes the recursion part that both of these functions would have in common and lets you only write the things they don't have in common.